# PHP fmod() returns wrong value when used with pow()

Tags: php, math, floating-point

So im trying to do a public private key equation which should be

Encrypted text = m^e mod n

where m is what needs to be encrypted ive tried alot of different things and none of them work

```
pow(20,37)%77;
```

this returns 0

```
fmod(pow(20,37), 77);
```

this returns 33

```
20^37%77;
```

this returns 49 which is the closests ive gotten to the correct answer of 48

i cant seem to figure out what is going wrong im assuming it might be a floating point issue but when doing this same equation in javascript and c# it works out perfect

if anyone could help me out or atleast get me on the right track that would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: 20 to the power of 37 is a huge number. You won't get sensible results with `pow()` or `fmod()` because you're going way beyond the capabilities of a double-precision floating point number. Use `bcpowmod(20,37,77)` instead. (Also, `^` is the XOR operator.)

Comment: Moreover if you want to encrypt i suggest to use pre-built librairies. Cryptography is not that easy.